# how to clear all map overlays or markers?

Tags: android, android-maps

I use that but markers still on the map.When I look overlays size after it looks like 0 but they also on the map.

How can I do that?

> mapView.getOverlays().clear();

Answer (score 1):

Call `mapView.invalidate()` after your cleared the overlays.

Comment: I want delete markers then add news. If I use this I cant use mapview again

Comment: Khm. Why can't you use mapView again? `invalidate()` just tells android, that it has to re-render the `View`. It's just a forced refresh.

Comment: I debugged it when I call >invalidate() after  >mapview.getoverlays().clear it says force close

Comment: I found problem is that I was trying invalidate() in another thread and map doesnt let this. Instead of invalidate() I clear map overlays list